# How to use two different versions of a program in Docker

Tags: docker

I am very new to Docker and learning about it. I have a question that might be very basic but I could not find the exact answer yet. So we know that using Docker we can containerize our apps so one app dependency will not have any effect on other apps. Suppose I have two apps on the host machine and both of the apps are in their own containers. Say, for example, one app is using python2 and another is using python3 (installed on their own containers). And just for the sake of argument, suppose that python3 has some features which are not present in python2. And I am working on both of the apps together. Now my question is when I work on a particular app, how can I use switch between the apps? I meant for example, inside a Database Management System we have different databases, and when we want to work on a particular database we write the command `use <databaseName>` and then we can work on that database. If both of my containers are running, when writing code, how can I specify or how does docker or my code editor know I want to work on the app which uses python2 now and then switch to another app that uses python3. Suppose, the host machine can not have both python2 and python3 together outside of containers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: @LinFelix Thanks for responding. I am most probably thinking in the wrong direction. I think I got my answer. Thanks anyways. :-)

Comment: If you got your answer, you can post it here, so that people with the same issue will have an easier time in the future